# Laravel-Missing required parameters

Tags: laravel-5, parameters

I want to pass Slug in the URL.Here is my code for link:

```
<a href="{{
           route('post.description',
                ['slug'=>$first_post->slug,
                 'id'=>Crypt::encrypt($first_post->id)]) }}"
</a>
```

My Route:

```
Route::get('/post/description/{slug}/{id}',[
   'uses'=>'FrontendController@description',
   'as'=>'post.description']);
```

And my Controller:

```
 public function description($slug,$id)
{
  $id=Crypt::decrypt($id);
  $data=Post::find($id);
  return view('description') ->with('data',$data)
}
```

But i'm getting the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kthyc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the array keys in the `route()` function, it is only the order that matters. Try changing your route function to this:

```
route('posts.description', [$first_post->slug, encrypt($first_post->id)])
```